# login shell check is not working in .profile

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, login, zsh

**Ubuntu 20.04, 5.8.0-63-generic, gnome-shell, gdm3**

My login shell is set to /bin/sh

and I have this line in my `$HOME/.profile` file:

```
shopt -q login_shell > /dev/null 2>&1 || export SHELL=/bin/zsh
```

Now from my understanding `export SHELL=/bin/zsh` should not be executed on login right? because it is a login shell so `shopt -q login_shell > /dev/null 2>&1` is True.

But I am getting $SHELL as /bin/zsh after login.

Actually setting $SHELL is not my concern, I want to use `shopt -q login_shell > /dev/null 2>&1` in .zshrc logic. I need to get that working to selectively run things in non-login shell.

Can't figure out what's going wrong. Need Help!

> Edit:

**Shopt is not a /bin/sh command. But even changing login shell to /bin/bash doesn't help.**

Answer (score 1):

`shopt` is not a valid command in the POSIX `sh` shell (nor `zsh`, which uses `setopt`/`unsetopt`), so will error out - making your test return non-zero unconditionally:

```
$ bash -lc 'shopt -q login_shell; echo $?'

0
```

but

```
$ sh -lc 'shopt -q login_shell; echo $?'
sh: 1: shopt: not found
127
```

and

```
$ zsh -lc 'shopt -q login_shell; echo $?'
zsh:1: command not found: shopt
127
```

Since `~/.profile` (as well as `/etc/profile`, plus the files in `/etc/profile.d` that it sources) may be read by other shells, best practice is to keep it POSIX complient. AFAIK the POSIX way to check for a login shell is to test whether `$0` begins with a `-` character ex.

```
case $0 in 
  -*) echo "login shell"
   ;; 
   *) echo "non-login shell"
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Right Thanks. But even changing to /bin/bash not working. What to do if I want to run something just during login. Edited the question.

Comment: @SayanDey I don't think `shopt` is legal in `zsh` either - it's `setopt`/`unsetopt`. IIRC the *portable* way to test for a login shell is to check if the first character of `$0` is a `-`. See edit.